# Subresource Integrity : script not blocked when integrity attribute is malformed

Tags: subresource-integrity

I am currently exploring the Subresource Integrity security feature and I found out an implementation that disturbs me a bit.
Basically, when you specify in a script that you want to check the integrity : it comes like this :

```
<script src="https://script.js"
        integrity="sha384-correct_hash"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Then, if the hash matches, the script is executed. If it doesn't, the script is blocked.

After this, I tried to trigger another error by suppressing the algorithm. I expected another error of the same kind, but I found out something else : the resource is not blocked. I understand this attribute is needed according to the specification, but I wanted to observe the implementation of this error.

My question is why is the script/stylesheet not blocked when you specify "integrity" without a formal algorithm (sha256/sha384/sha512) ?
As an example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Page</title>
</head>
<h2> My Test Page </h2>
<p>text for test(F12-->Console).</p>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
  $("p").hide()
</script>
```

The hash is the correct one, the stylesheet is applied and <p> elements are hidden using jquery.

If I modify the hash, the resources will be blocked.

But if I suppress the algo (shaXXX), whatever the hash I write, the ressource will be loaded and executed.
The browser just sends an error in the browser (chrome 110) :Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'). The hash algorithm must be one of 'sha256', 'sha384', or 'sha512', followed by a '-' character.
And with firefox(109) a warning.

ex :

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="not_a_good_hash"
      crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="Also_Not_A_GOOD_HASH"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

My view is : if a programmer specifies the integrity attribute, everything but the correct hash with the correct algo is supposed to be blocked. Can someone explain me this choice implementation, what are the reasons behind it ?

Comment: Per-spec, if the `shaNNN-` part of the attribute is missing, the attribute value is simply invalid — it’s not materially different from the case where the value is just some arbitrary string like `integrity="this-is-not-an-integrity-value"`. So the error message cited in the question is exactly what‘s expected, and conforms to the requirements in the spec.

Comment: The spec requires the browser to parse the value and throw when parsing fails. So a browser parsing the value begins by checking that the value starts with `sha256-|sha384-|sha512`. So if the value doesn’t start with `s`, then the browser stops right there and throws. Or if the value starts with `s` but not `sh`, then the browser stops right there and throws. And so on. Per-spec, what the browser does _not_ due is: It doesn’t attempt to check that the value is hash without a `sha-NNN` prefix, and then try guessing what algorithm might have been used to generate the hash.

Comment: If you believe the behavior should instead be that a script fails to load if the value of its `integrity` attribute is invalid, then the place to suggest that is in the issue tracker at https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-subresource-integrity. And if you want to know why the spec authors chose to have the behavior be that the script loads if the `integrity` value is invalid, the only people who can really answer that authoritatively are the spec authors.

Comment: Yes, my main question was about the behavior of this implementation. I am going to ask at github.com/w3c/webappsec-subresource-integrity. Thank you for your answer !